# Matching nominations with their codes

Tags: stata, social-networking, network-analysis

I’m working on network analysis and I have a dataset that looks like this

```
**ID-code | ego  |  alter1  |alter2 |alter3 |Office**
100       | JHON |  ROCKY   |JOE    |MOLLY  |   1
101       |ROCKY |  JOE     |MOLLY  |JHON   |   1
102       | JOE  |  MOLLY   |JHON   |  .    |   1
103       | MOLLY|  ROCKY   | .     |  .    |   1
```

As you can see each ego has been requested to name maximum three alters from the same office.

I would like to match the ID-codes with their names in order to get new variables/columns  something like this

```
   **ID-code ego|   ID_alter1   |ID_alter2  |ID_alter3**
    100JHON     |    101ROCKY   |102JOE     |103MOLLY
    101ROCKY    |    102JOE     |103MOLLY   |100JHON
    102JOE      |    103MOLLY   |100JHON    |    .
    103MOLLY    |    101ROCKY   |  .        |    .
```

I already know how to get the variable ID-code ego:

*`*egen ID-code ego= concat (ID-code ego)*`*

But I don’t know how to match the other observations with their ID-code.

any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
Amedeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin Crow wrote a vlookup clone that makes this very easy:

```
clear
input int id_code str5 ego str5 alter1 str5 alter2 str5 alter3
100 "JOHN" "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY"
101 "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN"
102 "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" ""
103 "MOLLY" "ROCKY" "" ""
end
capture net install vlookup, from(http://www.stata.com/users/kcrow)
gen id_code_ego = string(id) + ego
forvalues i=1/3 {
    vlookup alter`i', gen(code) key(ego) value(id_code)
    gen id_alter`i' = string(code) + alter`i'
    drop alter`i' code
}
drop id_code ego
```

---

Addendum:

```
clear
input int id_code str5 ego str5 alter1 str5 alter2 str5 alter3 int officer
100 "JOHN" "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" 1
101 "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" 1
102 "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" "" 1
103 "MOLLY" "ROCKY" "" "" 1
103 "JOHN" "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" 2
102 "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" 2
101 "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" "" 2
100 "MOLLY" "ROCKY" "" "" 2
end
capture net install vlookup, from(http://www.stata.com/users/kcrow)

gen id_code_ego_officer = string(id) + ego + string(officer)
gen ego_officer = ego + string(office)

forvalues i=1/3 {
    replace alter`i'= alter`i' + string(officer) 
    vlookup alter`i', gen(code) key(ego_officer) value(id_code)
    gen id_alter`i' = string(code) + alter`i'
    replace id_alter`i' = regexr(id_alter`i',"[0-9]?$","")
    drop alter`i' code  
}

drop id_code_ego_officer ego_officer
```

Comment: Dear Dimitriy. Thank you so much for your help. Because I have subjects with the same name in my list I get the error **"Id-code is unique within ego;
there are multiple observations with different id-code within ego." **Therefor I would like to specify to run your command for each office (you can see the variable office in the first table). Within offices i don't have double names. I have tried with a `bys office: ` but vlookup doesn't accept `by` command.

Comment: @Amedeo That is a key detail that's not mentioned in your original question. The solution is to redefine things to be officer specific.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was clear since there is the variable in the table and I said that the alters are from the same office. My mistake.  Moreover, I didn't know that vlookup doesn't accept the by command, Thanks for your help Dimitriy

Answer (score 1):

To match values from other observations, the typical approach in Stata is to use `merge`. In a first step, you create a master list of distinct values of ego per office. Then you go back to the original data and merge each alter with the distinct office names. Some variable name renaming is required to perform the merge:

```
clear
input int id_code str5 ego str5 alter1 str5 alter2 str5 alter3 int office
100 "JOHN" "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" 1
101 "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" 1
102 "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" "" 1
103 "MOLLY" "ROCKY" "" "" 1
103 "JOHN" "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" 2
102 "ROCKY" "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" 2
101 "JOE" "MOLLY" "JOHN" "" 2
100 "MOLLY" "ROCKY" "" "" 2
end

* make a master list of unique id/name per office
preserve
keep office id_code ego
isid office id_code ego, sort
rename (id_code ego) (id0 ego0)
save "match_egos.dta", replace
restore

* combine the id/ego for each observation
gen ID_ego = string(id_code) + ego

* loop over each alter and merge with the master list
forvalues i = 1/3 {
    clonevar ego0 = alter`i'
    merge m:1 office ego0 using "match_egos.dta", keep(master match) nogen
    gen ID_alter`i' = string(id0) + alter`i'
    drop ego0 id0
}

isid office id_code ego, sort
* leftalign is from SSC; to install, type in Command window: ssc install left align
leftalign
list ID_*, sepby(office)
```